# Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty i p_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty q_i$

Tags: probability, algorithms

Given a table with m slots, indexed $0,1,\dots, m-1$ and n keys that are included in this table, $n \lt m$, with $m-n$ slots being empty, I'm given an algorithm that given a certain permutation of the m indices, searches the slots in the order of the given permutation for a particular key k and stops once it either finds the slot with key k (in which case TRUE is returned) or stops once it encounters an empty slot (returns FALSE).

In this case the question assumes that the search is always unsuccessful, i.e. the key k is not included in the table.

Let $p_i$ be the probability that the algorithm accesses exactly i occupied, i.e. non-empty slots in its search and let $q_i$ be the probability that it accesses at least i slots in its search.

Now obviously the search always ends with an attempt to access an empty slot. So e.g. the probability $p_2 = \frac{n}{m}\frac{n-1}{m-1}\frac{m-2-n}{m-2}$.

Since $q_i$ is the probability that at least i-times an occupied slot has been accessed, it follows that $q_i = 1-\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}p_j$.

Now the question asks one to prove equivalence of two infinite sequences, but since only n slots are occupied, we have $\sum_{i=0}^\infty i p_i = \sum_{i=1}^n i p_i$, same with the sum for $q_i$(the reason for using an infinite series is that you should use the closed form of an infinite geometric series in a later part of the exercise).

So we would have:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_i = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 0p_0 + 1p_1 + \dots + np_n$$

and

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty q_i = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i = 1-p_0 + 1-p_0-p_1 + \dots + 1 -p_0-\dots -p_{n-1}$$
$$ =n - np_0 - (n-1)p_1 - \dots p_{n-1} $$

Now I'm not sure how to continue from here. How can I prove that these two expressions are equivalent? Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there's a typo in the definition of $q_i$ and that it should be:

$\qquad$ the probability that it accesses at least $i$ **occupied** slots in its search.

(This agrees with your working.)

We have: $\qquad q_i = \sum_{j=i}^{\infty}{p_j}$.

So,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{q_i} &=& \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}{p_j}\right)} \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{i p_i}\qquad\mbox{(since each $p_i$ appears $i$ times)}.
\end{eqnarray*}